# Loss in Tensorflow suddenly turn into nan

Tags: tensorflow, nan, loss

When I using tensorflow, the loss suddenly turn into nan, just like:

```
Epoch:  00001 || cost= 0.675003929
Epoch:  00002 || cost= 0.237375346
Epoch:  00003 || cost= 0.204962473
Epoch:  00004 || cost= 0.191322120
Epoch:  00005 || cost= 0.181427178
Epoch:  00006 || cost= 0.172107664
Epoch:  00007 || cost= 0.171604740
Epoch:  00008 || cost= 0.160334495
Epoch:  00009 || cost= 0.151639721
Epoch:  00010 || cost= 0.149983061
Epoch:  00011 || cost= 0.145890004
Epoch:  00012 || cost= 0.141182279
Epoch:  00013 || cost= 0.140914166
Epoch:  00014 || cost= 0.136189088
Epoch:  00015 || cost= 0.133215346
Epoch:  00016 || cost= 0.130046664
Epoch:  00017 || cost= 0.128267926
Epoch:  00018 || cost= 0.125328618
Epoch:  00019 || cost= 0.125053261
Epoch:  00020 || cost= nan
Epoch:  00021 || cost= nan
Epoch:  00022 || cost= nan
Epoch:  00023 || cost= nan
Epoch:  00024 || cost= nan
Epoch:  00025 || cost= nan
Epoch:  00026 || cost= nan
Epoch:  00027 || cost= nan
```

And the main training code is:

```
for epoch in range(1000):
    Mcost = 0

    temp = []
    for i in range(total_batch):
        batch_X = X[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
        batch_Y = Y[i*batch_size:(i+1)*batch_size]
        solver, c, pY = sess.run([train, cost, y_conv], feed_dict={x: batch_X, y_: batch_Y, keep_prob:0.8})
        Mcost = Mcost + c

    print("Epoch: ", '%05d'%(epoch+1), "|| cost=",'{:.9f}'.format(Mcost/total_batch))
```

Since the cost is OK at the first 19 epoch, I believe that the network and the input is OK. For the network, I use 4 CNN, the activate function is relu, and the last layer is full connect without the activate function.

Also, I have known that 0/0 or log(0) will result in nan. But, my loss function is:

```
c1 = y_conv - y_
c2 = tf.square(c1)
c3 = tf.reduce_sum(c2,1)
c4 = tf.sqrt(c3)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(c4)
```

I run the tensorflow with GPU GTX 1080.

Any suggestion is appreciate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quite often, those `NaN` come from a divergence in the optimization due to increasing gradients. They usually don't appear at once, but rather after a phase where the loss increases suddenly and within a few steps reaches `inf`. The reason you do not see this explosive increase is probably because you check your loss only every epoch -- try to display your loss every step or every few steps and you are likely to see this phenomenon.

As to why your gradient exploses suddenly, I would suggest you try without `tf.sqrt` in your loss function. This should be more numerically stable. `tf.sqrt` has the bad property of having an exploding gradient near zero. This means increasing risks of divergence once you get close to a solution -- looks a lot like what you are observing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. And the tf.sqrt may be the question. However, when I exclude the tf.sqrt, the decrease of loss is very slow. I don't know the reason. Then, I change c2 = tf.square(c1) to c2 = tf.square(c1) + 1. And the decrease of loss is OK.