# How can I implement marginal loss?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, loss-function

I am trying to implement the marginal loss introduced in the paper [1]. 
So far this is what I have done.

```
def marginal_loss(model1, model2, y, margin, threshold):
    margin_ = 1/(tf.pow(margin,2)-margin)
    tmp = (1. - y)
    euc_dist = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(model1-model2, 2), 1, keep_dims=True))
    thres_dist = threshold - euc_dist
    mul_val = tf.multiply(tmp, thres_dist)
    sum_ = tf.reduce_sum(mul_val)
    return tf.multiply(margin_, sum_)
```

However, after some epochs, the value goes to nan. I am not sure what mistake I made. Furthermore, I have used 1 instead of epsilon (described in the paper) because its value was not clear. Similarly, the exact threshold value is also not known.

Thanks for any help.

[1] https://ibug.doc.ic.ac.uk/media/uploads/documents/deng_marginal_loss_for_cvpr_2017_paper.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This looks very similar to the problem raised by [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44497446/1735003). The problem may come from the use of `tf.sqrt`, which has the bad property of having gradients going to infinity as you approach zero, bringing you instabilities as your model converges.

Try to get rid of the `tf.sqrt` in your loss, for example by minimizing the square of your current loss.

Alternatively you can rely on existing built-in functions like [`tf.losses.hinge_loss`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/hinge_loss) (not for multidimensional outputs though).

Comment: Without tf.sqrt, the loss is in -ve. The main problem is not nan, probably due to faulty implementation. It is the implementation. Can you please look if my implementation is correct or not?

Comment: These negative values are probably due to threshold values; I am not sure what exact threshold value is. I set it to 1 (causes negative values), when I change it to 0 (it is normal), the loss decreases in both cases. But I am not sure about the implementation.